# How to filter nested list with JPA Specification directly in the query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class ScheduleCourierEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "courier", cascade = ALL, fetch = LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ScheduleDayAvailabilityEntity> weekAvailability = new ArrayList<>();
   
}
```

```
 @Entity
 @Table
 public class ScheduleDayAvailabilityEntity extends BaseEntity {
 
     @Enumerated(STRING)
     private DayOfWeek weekDay;
 
     @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
     private ScheduleCourierEntity courier;
 
 }
```

A ScheduleCourierEntity can have availabilities for every week day (7 elements). I am using JPA Specification to retrieve the courier that has the availability for a specific DayOfWeek, let's say FRIDAY. I want to make the query return ScheduleCourierEntity the list containing only one element, the ScheduleDayAvailabilityEntity of FRIDAY, so that:

1. Memory won't be loaded with unnecessary data
2. I won't have to filter out FRIDAY out of the other days

Is there any possible way to achieve that?
Thanks in advance

This is the Specification method:

```
 @Override
 public Predicate toPredicate(@NonNull Root<ScheduleCourierEntity> root, @NonNull CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
     this.root = root;
     this.criteriaBuilder = criteriaBuilder;
     Join<Object, Object> weekAvailabilityJoin = root.join(WEEK_AVAILABILITY);
     Path<Object> path = weekAvailabilityJoin.get(WEEK_DAY);
     predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(path, searchRequest.getDate().getDayOfWeek()));
     query.distinct(true);
     return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
}
```

I only managed to retrieve a courier that has the required day, but it always comes with a list of 7 elements.